# Remove Unnecessary Spaces on Themes

Tags: css, wordpress

We are using twenty sixteen word press theme.

The theme has lot of header and footer spaces which would like to remove.

Eventhough we didn't provide any banner or any other images it still have more spaces before the table gets generated in the page or page content

any suggestion on how or where to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to edit the theme, you will have to modify it's css.

Comment: it says it is not recommended to change..could you please let me know where to do it?

Comment: Since there are several places, and you have not specified each, if you are not aware about CSS then the best bet would be for you to hire a web designer or use a different theme.

Comment: You can add the CSS by using a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click on the empty space annoying you and click inspect in chrome. It will show you something like this...

[image]

Here... Faint Green outline is the padding... this is causing that annoying whitespace,

```
.site-header {
  padding: 5.25em 4.5455%;
}
```

Just kill it with CSS, you need higher specificity ( Learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ) for beginners simply prefix `body` before selector and it will have higher specificity and will work like a charm...

```
body .site-header {
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can also use `!important`...

```
.site-header {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Using `!important` is not a good practice coz it breaks the heirarchy but since you are designing the site not writing a plugin it's up to you ;)

You can use this for any element, try yourself for footer

You can add the CSS by using a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: if i add the custom css will it override the existing default css and causes any issue

Comment: We can always override default css to make the site look the way we want it to, that's how we customize themes whenever we want (which is always) 

Comment: This bit of CSS will only override padding on header 